# Asymptotes of a General Rational Function

Tags: rational-functions

> $f(x)$ is a rational function of the form $f(x)=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx+e}$ and the function $g(x)$ is given by $g(x)=\frac{4}{f(x)}$. It is known that $f(x)$ has an oblique asymptote $y=x+1$ and $g(x)$ has vertical asymptotes $x=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt3}{2}  $. Find all the values of $x$ for which $f(x)=g(x)$.

The answer is $x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt19}{2}$.

Vertical asymptotes of $g(x)$ are when $f(x)=0$ which is when $ax^2+bx+c=0$

Therefore

$ax^2+bx+c=(x-(\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2}))(x-(\frac{1- \sqrt 3}{2}))=0$

$2x^2-2x-1=0$

$f(x)=\frac{2x^2-2x-1}{dx+e}=\frac{2}{d}x-\frac{2}{d}(1+\frac{e}{d})+\frac{1+\frac{2e}{d}+\frac{2e^2}{d^2}}{dx+e}$

$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\frac{2}{d}x-\frac{2}{d}(1+\frac{e}{d})=2x+1$

Therefore $d=2$ and $e=-4$

$f(x)=\frac{2x^2-2x-1}{2x-4}$

$g(x)=\frac{4(2x-4)}{2x^2-2x-1}$

$f(x)=g(x)$

$\sqrt((2x^-2x-1)^2)=\sqrt(4(2x-4)^2)$

$2x^2-2x-1=2(2x-4)$

$2x^2-6x+7$

which gives no solutions

I didn't think that method would work as it does not take into account the $\pm$ of the square root.

Expanding gave the equation

$4x^4-8x^3-16x^2+68x-63=0$

which gives 4 solutions,

$x = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt19}{2}$, and the two complex solutions $\frac{3\pm\sqrt5 i}{2}$

which actually gives the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've got $a,b,c,e$ and $d$, so I'll take it from here.

Instead of writing $$f(x) = g(x)$$

I will write $$f(x) = \frac{4}{f(x)}$$

$$f(x)^2 = 4 $$

Then $$f(x) = ± 2$$

Taking $f(x) = 2$ gives: $2x^2 - 6x + 7 = 0$, which has no real solutions.

Taking $f(x) = -2$ gives:  $2x^2 + 2x - 9 = 0$, which has the two aforementioned solutions.

Hope this helps!